# Any tool to show you all elements/pages in a site that are affected by a particular CSS rule?

Tags: html, css

Of course we can use tools like Firebug to highlight portions of HTML and see what all CSS is being applied.

But what about the reverse?  Is there some kind of tool which would allow you to highlight a particular CSS rule and show you all the pages on a site (either static HTML pages or their dynamic templates) that it applies to?

Example: I've come to work on a new site, very large and I need to edit CSS on a particular page but in doing so, I have no idea how many other pages on the site might also have these class names and hence be affected.  Of course I can try to search the whole site for the class name(s) but this can be time consuming or tricky.  This site has a class named "ba" for example.  Guess how many irrelevant pages will turn up if I just search for "ba"?  So how about including a double quote ("ba)?  Well, it could be in the middle of a few other classes (class="hz ba top"), at the end (class="hz ba"), etc.  More so, it could be dynamically plugged in via server side code making it even harder to find.  A tool that could somehow spider your site and be able to identify all the places your CSS change will affect would be great.

Answer (score 1):

not exactly that, but there is a firebug plugin that does that for any loaded page:

http://robertnyman.com/firefinder/

Comment: well, not really what i need but thanks.  i'm skilled enough to know what the CSS selectors would do to the page i'm working on, it's just the other X hundred i'm blind to.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions ..

for example in Dreamweaver on the search dialog box :

1. select 'Find in: Entire current local site.."
2. select 'Search: Source code'
3. check 'Use regular expression'
4. in the find textarea type `class\s*?=\s*?".*?content.*?"`
5. click 'find all'

the same regular expression could be used with other software that can search inside files using regular expressions....
for example : http://www.sowsoft.com/search.htm (not affiliated with them, just found it for here..)

Keep in mind though, that all the suggestions here do not take into account the case where the class is added by script..

Comment: well, that's still searching for a class across the code, which is one way (better to do like you point out w/ regex) but best would be a tool that could somehow keep track of all pages enough to tell you all the pages that a particular CSS rule would apply to.  so you would know all the pages an edit to an existing CSS rule would apply to.

Comment: Use this regexp instead: `class.*content.*`
That is most generic and will get you everything you need, including cases like:
`class => "content"`,
`class = 'content'`,
`class = "otherclass content otherclass"`,
`class="otherclass content"`,
`class: "content"`
and so forth... (where _content_ is _ba_ or whatever class you are searching for)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Mac, there's an excellent shareware app called "[CSSEdit](http://macrabbit.com/cssedit/)" by an Indy Mac Shop in Belgium. A single-user license is 30 euros. I've used it for approx. three years and i can recommend it highly. It's a mature, stable App (though continuously updated/improved); widely used among Mac Web Designers, and those of use who are not but need all the help we can get, which CSSEdit certainly seems to provide.

To show elements on the html page styled by a given selector:

(i) open both the style sheet and the markup page (markup page must have a link to the style sheet);

(ii) click the X-Ray button off (must read 'Not Active' below the button);

(iii) in the style editor, click any selector (i click it so that my cursor is at the left margin, e.g., in front of the '#', etc.);

(iv) now click 'inspector' on the mark-up page (next to 'X-ray').

Now, look at your mark-up page--it will have a blue outline around the elements affect by the style you clicked on in step (iii) above.

Comment: really?  looking at it, the X-Ray Inspector seems to basically just be like Firebug.  that is, i can inspect an element to find the CSS applied to it, but what about inspecting a CSS rule and finding all the pages across a site it's used on?  does it do that?

Comment: with both the style sheet and the markup page open: (i) click the X-Ray button off; (ii) in the style editor, click any style (i click it so that my cursor is at the left margin, e.g., in front of the '#', etc.); (iii) now click 'inspector' on the mark-up page (next to 'X-ray'). Now, look at your mark-up page--it will have a blue outline around the elements affect by the style you clicked on.

Comment: sorry, i think my question's title is misleading.  i'm actually looking for something that highlighting a style will show the mark up it affects site-wide (all pages/templates), not just on one particular page.  basically, a way to edit a CSS rule and know what all pages across the site it will affect.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of things I just use `grep`, or - even better, [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/).
If you're concerned about false positive when searching for short patterns, you can do a double filter: you grep all lines containing `class=` and you feed its output in another grep which only narrows the result down to the lines containing both `class=` and your search pattern (which can also be more precisely specified with a regexp using word boundaries like `\bba\b` to avoid matching `bar` or `abba`)

Answer (score 0):

How about putting an ID on the body of each page, and use that to restrain the use of CSS outside of pages clearly stated in the CSS?

Like this:

```
#mypage .description,
#myotherpage . description {
}
```

Cons:

- Must put a body ID on each page / template.
- Must specify each page the CSS should apply to. More CSS code to manage.
- Makes the CSS less easy to scan through with your eyes (since the line starts with the page ID and not the CSS style). This is a bigger problem if some of the CSS styles are used on several pages (since the css spec for each style would be long).

Pros:

- Avoids unintentioned CSS change propagations. I.e. changing one page affects other unknown pages.
- See what pages a CSS change would affect, when you're editing the CSS style itself. The information is right there; no need to search/grep for it.
- Forces developers to specify what pages the CSS would affect. If you'd just included this information as comments in your CSS, some person would inevitably forget to update the comment when the CSS is used on a new page.

I agree with this statement, made by a friend:

*"Minimize CSS that is used several places. It's not like programming; it's better with a little duplicate CSS, than unmanageable CSS. (Pages like apple.com, has own stylesheets for
each page, and some global CSS.)"* 
 - Olav Bjørkøy, original creator of the Blueprint CSS framework

I'd love your input on this, or if any of you have found a better way.

Comment: Actually, after a lot of back and forth, I've decided to drop this whole approach. We were able to eliminate the maintainability overhead, and go with a solution that works sufficiently enough. We just have to be a bit more careful:
1. Giving semantic names to styles. Generic ones for those that are used generically. This serves as a trigger to search for other uses.
2. For those with generic names: Remember to search for alternate uses in the project (CMD+SHIFT+F in Sublime Text 2, and use the regexp: _class.*submit.*_ ), so we know about other pages that will be affected by the change.